# Django Sessions with Multiple Heroku Dynos

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I've built a simple website with  a login/logout in Django and deployed to Heroku. I'm using the builtin Django auth Users. I've verified that when users login, they see a profile page and upon refresh they remain logged in.

When I bump up the number of Heroku dynos to more than 1, sessions are no longer persistent. What I mean by this is that after a user logs in, after a refresh or two, the user is logged out. I believe this is because each request goes to a particular dyno, each of which maintain session state in isolation? Obviously my site cannot operate when sessions are only valid if the user happens to request from the right dyno.

To try to address this problem and allow my Django app to use more than one dyno, I used [django-redis-sessions](https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions) thinking that all the dynos could share access to a single Redis cluster that stores session information. When I retry to bump up the dyno count above 1, the problem immediately returns even though sessions are being written to the Redis cluster.

Am I missing something? This is my first time trying to scale Django on Heroku. Thank you!

Some relevant sections of my production settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',          # User Authentication App
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  # Dependency of auth
    'django.contrib.sessions',      # Database backed sessions
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',   # Collect and store static resources
    'storages',                     # Custom Django Storage Backends
    'djcelery',                     # Celery Queueing
    'kombu.transport.django',       # Use database as a Celery queue
    'app_pkg.apps.web',
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session'

SESSION_REDIS_HOST = 'servername.redistogo.com'
SESSION_REDIS_PORT = 9357
SESSION_REDIS_DB = 0
SESSION_REDIS_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
SESSION_REDIS_PREFIX = 'session'
```

EDIT:
I had this issue before ever integrating Redis into my application. I started using Redis session store as a way of centralizing the location where sessions were stored without realizing that the database already does this. If its any use, the database in use is Amazon RDS via the Heroku addon. I'll factor out usage of Redis, verify that I still have the issue, and report back.

Comment: sessions are based on a cookie value and a *database* by default, which isn't even aware of the heroku dyno. It simply looks up the session cookie ID in the DB. You should confirm that the cookies are staying consistent. You could also look at the database calls (debug mode spits out SQL) to see what its doing.

Comment: I think your above code should work... Can you store other things in the session? and are they also forgotten when you change dynos?  That would help pin it down to a redis configuration, or an authentication thing.

Comment: As mentioned in my edit, I don't think the problem is related to redis configuration as the issue existed before I integrated Redis into my application. I will do further testing soon and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Django sessions are persisted in the database. Dynos shouldn't affect them in any way.

Comment: I think a key line here is the `SESSION_ENGINE` setting, where they change it from a database store, to a redis store.  Does the auth module work differently?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a different redis addon for each application dyno, or attaching the same one to all dynos?  You would need the latter to share sessions!

Also note that redis connections are not secured by default.  I am not sure if sessions are encrypted with the app SECRET_KEY or if they are exploitable if someone gets the REDIS_URL.